# Aerospike client connections for a node is very high than other nodes in cluster and causing read connection timeouts

Tags: aerospike

We are using aerospike-go-client to access data from aerospike cluster

and we are facing "**read: connection timed out**" issues

We monitored all the nodes using AMC(Aerospike Management Console), Of them one of the node is behaving badly in number of client connections it has ~5-6 times more client connections than others. And we are expecting this might be the reason for the issue

What are the possible reasons for these timeouts, and what is the resolution for it?

P.S All the nodes in the cluster machines are of same configuration

Comment: Which language client are you using?

Comment: @RonenBotzer, I am using aerospike Go Client